# Error when using HTML, Javascript, MySQL and PHP combined to submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

My form doesn't get submitted although I see the alert "Your message was sent!". Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Here're the codes I have written. I have a table called messages in my database to insert form data entered from HTML form. Thanks!

HTML file

```
<form action="javascript:contactSubmit();" name="front_home_contact">
    <div class="front_home_details_field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="home_contact_field" required pattern="[A-z ]+"/>
    </div>
    <div class="front_home_details_field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="home_contact_field" required  pattern="0[0-9]{9}" maxlength="10"/>
    </div>
    <div class="front_home_details_field">
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="home_contact_field" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="front_home_details_field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="home_contact_field" required pattern="[A-z s]+"/>
    </div>
    <div class="front_home_details_field" style="height:151px;">
        <textarea placeholder="Message" name="home_contact_field" aria-invalid="false" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="home_contact_field"/>
</form>
```

Javascript .js file

```
function contactSubmit(){

    document.front_home_contact.setAttribute("novalidate","true");
    var elems = document.getElementsByName("front_home_contact"); //or
    var xhrx = (window.XMLHttpRequest)? new XMLHttpRequest(): new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("func","insertMsg");
    data.append("arg",elems);
    alert("Your message was sent!");
        /*xhrx.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhrx.readyState==4 && xhrx.status==200){
                reportSection.innerHTML= xhrx.responseText.trim(); 
                httpComplete +=1;
                if (httpComplete == 3) elem.style.display="block";
        }
        }*/
    xhrx.open('post','insertMessages.php',true);
    xhrx.send(data);
    for (i = 0; i< elems.length;i++){
        elems[i].value="";
    }
}
```

PHP file (`insertMessages.php`)

```
<?php 
    include "config.php";
    $function = $_POST['func'];
    if ($function == "insertMsg"){
        $query = "INSERT INTO `messages`(`SenderName`, `PhoneNumber`, `Email`, `Subject`, `Message`) VALUES ('".$_POST['args'][0]."');";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('OK');</script>";
        }
        else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('error');</script>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Are you making an AJAX call or a form submit?

Comment: What is `$_POST['args'][0]`? That's not going to be 5 values. That also would open you to SQL injections if it would to work. Parameterize.

Comment: FYI, javascript alert in PHP inside ajax call won't work. `$_POST['args'][0]` is the only value you are passing against 5 placeholders

Comment: @chris85  Then how to include form data to sql query?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: If it is an array use each value, `$_POST['args'][0]`, `$_POST['args'][1]`, etc.   you'll need to quote those values and separate by comma. This also will still be open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can not display `alert()` from ajax response.

Define `onreadystatechange` and define the action you want to perform based on your response.

Directly don't pass `script` in php response.

Pass `success / error` (if possible just use JSON in sending response) and after receiving in response just check the value and perform action you want to perform.

like,

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      if( this.responseText=="success"){
           alert('OK');
      }else{
           alert('error');
      }
   }
};
```